# Getting NullPointerException during launch

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have nine buttons, each of which punches in a number to an EditText, kind of like a calculator. I'm just doing this as a simple project, but I keep receiving these NullPointerExeptions. If I run it with only the pre-made onCreate() method, it seems to work but once I start declaring variables under the class declaration, it throws some exceptions. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numdisplay);
Button clearbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
Button ninenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nine);
Button eightnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eight);
Button sevennum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seven);
Button sixnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.six);
Button fivenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.five);
Button fournum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.four);
Button threenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.three);
Button twonum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
Button onenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
Button enterbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    onclicks(); //setting all the onclick listeners
}

public void onclicks() { //just setting onclick listeners, so it doesn't bloat up the oncreate method
    clearbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ninenum.setOnClickListener(this);
    eightnum.setOnClickListener(this);
    sevennum.setOnClickListener(this);
    sixnum.setOnClickListener(this);
    fivenum.setOnClickListener(this);
    fournum.setOnClickListener(this);
    threenum.setOnClickListener(this);
    twonum.setOnClickListener(this);
    onenum.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.clear: /** More switch cases will be put here*/
           display.setText("");
           break;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

place this code

```
ditText display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numdisplay);
Button clearbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
Button ninenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nine);
Button eightnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eight);
Button sevennum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seven);
Button sixnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.six);
Button fivenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.five);
Button fournum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.four);
Button threenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.three);
Button twonum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
Button onenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
Button enterbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
```

inside of `onCreate()` after `setContentView`

Because

you won't get your views reference untill you `setContentView` in `onCreate()`, so when you are trying to get the reference outside of `onCreate()` you'll get `null` reference, and accessing `null` will give you `NullPointerException`

Declare like this

```
Button clearbtn ,ninenum ,eightnum ,sevennum ,sixnum ,fivenum ,fivenum ,fournum ,threenum ,twonum ,onenum ,enterbtn ;
EditText display;
```

And in onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numdisplay);
clearbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
ninenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nine);
eightnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eight);
sevennum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seven);
sixnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.six);
fivenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.five);
fournum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.four);
threenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.three);
twonum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
onenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
enterbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Findviewbyid  will return only after you setcontentView that layout. What you are doing is trying to retrive on class load.

Try adding

```
EditText display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numdisplay);
Button clearbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
Button ninenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nine);
Button eightnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eight);
Button sevennum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seven);
Button sixnum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.six);
Button fivenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.five);
Button fournum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.four);
Button threenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.three);
Button twonum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.two);
Button onenum = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
Button enterbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
```

after `setContentView` statement

Answer (score 0):

`setContentview()` is used to set the activity content to explicit view, so before referencing to a view you cannot use the controls within.

try below code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText display;
Button clearbtn,ninenum,eightnum,sevennum,sixnum,fivenum,fournum,threenum,twonum,onenum,enterbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numdisplay);
    onclicks(); //setting all the onclick listeners
}

public void onclicks() { //just setting onclick listeners, so it doesn't bloat up the oncreate method
    clearbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ninenum.setOnClickListener(this);
    eightnum.setOnClickListener(this);
    sevennum.setOnClickListener(this);
    sixnum.setOnClickListener(this);
    fivenum.setOnClickListener(this);
    fournum.setOnClickListener(this);
    threenum.setOnClickListener(this);
    twonum.setOnClickListener(this);
    onenum.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.clear: /** More switch cases will be put here*/
           display.setText("");
           break;
}
}
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: It's still throwing the exception. This is what happened originally, and I'm not sure why. I made sure the the onclicklisteners and the edittext were put after the SetContentView portion.

Comment: @ThatGuyThere: try and replace your complete code with above code...if still problem persists put your log here